# tf.nn.static_rnn - input must be a sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, lstm, word-embedding

I'm trying to create a 2 layer lstm (incl. dropout) but get an error message that 'inputs must be a sequence'.

I use embeddings as the input and not sure how to change these to be a sequence? Any explanations are greatly appreciated.

This is my graph definition:

```
    with tf.name_scope('Placeholders'):
        input_x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, n_steps], name='input_x')
        input_y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_classes], name='input_y')
        dropout_keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='dropout_keep_prob')


    with tf.name_scope('Embedding_layer'):
        embeddings_var = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([vocab_size, EMBEDDING_DIM], -1.0, 1.0), trainable=True)
        embedded_chars = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings_var, input_x)
        print(embedded_chars, 'embed')


    def get_a_cell(lstm_size, keep_prob):
        lstm = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(lstm_size)
        drop = tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(lstm, output_keep_prob=dropout_keep_prob)
        return drop


    with tf.name_scope('lstm'):
        cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell(
            [get_a_cell(num_hidden, dropout_keep_prob) for _ in range(num_layers)]
        )

    lstm_outputs, state = tf.nn.static_rnn(cell=cell,inputs=embedded_chars, dtype=tf.float32)

    with tf.name_scope('Fully_connected'):
        W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_hidden, n_classes], stddev=0.1))
        b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=n_classes))
        output = tf.nn.xw_plus_b(lstm_outputs,W,b)
        predictions = tf.argmax(output, 1, name='predictions')

    with tf.name_scope('Loss'):
        # Cross-entropy loss and optimizer initialization
        loss1 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=output, labels=input_y))
        global_step = tf.Variable(0, name="global_step", trainable=False)
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-3).minimize(loss1, global_step=global_step)

    with tf.name_scope('Accuracy'):
        # Accuracy metrics
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(tf.round(tf.nn.softmax(output)), input_y), tf.float32))

    with tf.name_scope('num_correct'):
        correct_predictions = tf.equal(predictions, tf.argmax(input_y, 1))
        num_correct = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(correct_predictions, 'float'), name='num_correct')
```

EDIT: 
when changing static_rnn to dynamic_rnn the error message changes to the following, failing on the bias (b) variable:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

After I changed the bias term to this:

```
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
```

and get a new error message:

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 3 for 'Fully_connected/xw_plus_b/MatMul' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [?,27,128], [128,6].
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we assume you use `tf.dynamic_rnn` (for the case of `tf.static_rnn`, the first problem is because you don't give the input in the right format, `tf.static_rnn` except a sequence of tensor such as list of tensors `[batch_size x seq_len]` and not a single tensor with shape `[batch_size x seq_len x dim]` whereas `tf.dynamic_rnn` deals with such tensors as input)

I invite you to read the documentation of [tf.nn_dynamic_rnn](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn) to see that for your classification problem you might not want to use `lstm_outputs` but `state` which basically contain the last output of your RNN, because lstm_output contains all the outputs , whereas here you are interested on only in the last_output (except if you want to do something like attention for classification , here you'll need all the outputs).

To get the last output you'll basically need to do that:

```
lstm_outputs, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=cell,inputs=embedded_chars, dtype=tf.float32)
last_output = state[-1].h
```

`state[-1]` to take the state of the last cell, then `h` contains the last output and pass `last_output` to your feed forward network.

## Full code

(working, but compute wrong accuracy see comments)

```
n_classes = 6
n_steps = 27
num_hidden=128
dropout_keep_prob =0.5
vocab_size=10000
EMBEDDING_DIM=300
num_layers = 2

with tf.name_scope('Placeholders'):
    input_x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, n_steps], name='input_x')
    input_y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_classes], name='input_y')
    dropout_keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='dropout_keep_prob')


with tf.name_scope('Embedding_layer'):
    embeddings_var = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([vocab_size, EMBEDDING_DIM], -1.0, 1.0), trainable=True)
    embedded_chars = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings_var, input_x)
    print(embedded_chars, 'embed')


def get_a_cell(lstm_size, keep_prob):
    lstm = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(lstm_size)
    drop = tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(lstm, output_keep_prob=dropout_keep_prob)
    return drop


with tf.name_scope('lstm'):
    cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell(
        [get_a_cell(num_hidden, dropout_keep_prob) for _ in range(num_layers)]
    )

lstm_outputs, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=cell,inputs=embedded_chars, dtype=tf.float32)
last_output = state[-1].h
with tf.name_scope('Fully_connected'):
    W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_hidden, n_classes], stddev=0.1))
    b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[n_classes]))
    output = tf.nn.xw_plus_b(last_output,W,b)
    predictions = tf.argmax(output, 1, name='predictions')

with tf.name_scope('Loss'):
    # Cross-entropy loss and optimizer initialization
    loss1 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=output, labels=input_y))
    global_step = tf.Variable(0, name="global_step", trainable=False)
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-3).minimize(loss1, global_step=global_step)

with tf.name_scope('Accuracy'):
    # Accuracy metrics
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(tf.round(tf.nn.softmax(output)), input_y), tf.float32))

with tf.name_scope('num_correct'):
    correct_predictions = tf.equal(predictions, tf.argmax(input_y, 1))
    num_correct = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(correct_predictions, 'float'), name='num_correct')
```

Comment: thank you for your explanation @abcdaire (I'm quite new to tensorflow) , I made the changes as suggested (using last_output and keeping the amendment for the bias term) but received further error messages: ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 64 and 6 for 'Accuracy/Equal' (op: 'Equal') with input shapes: [?,64], [?,6].  I know that 64 = hidden_units and 6 = number of labels - is this also a reshaping issue?

Comment: @msa This is weird, I don't have any issue , I'll edit my answer with the code

Comment: @msa The code should work, but apart from that the way you computed the accuracy is not very accurate :p , imagine the case where your softmax outputs 0.3,0.2,0.3,0.1,0.1 (everything gets rounded to 0), the best thing is to use what is already available: `accuracy=tf.metrics.accuracy(tf.argmax(input_y,axis=1),predictions)`

Comment: thank you for your help! I just had another look and edited the accuracy too! It seems to be working now :)

Comment: Happy to help ! As a next challenge , I'll suggest to you to use dynamic_rnn properly and take advantage of the possibility of handling various sequence length :) (padding to a max_seq_len , then create a function get_length() that is able to retrieve from a padded batch the dimension of each sample, so then you pass length=get_length(embeded_chars) to the dynamic_rnn)

Comment: that's a good idea - I'm trying to get more familiar by trying to get all 'popular' types of neural networks working. Do you see any specific advantage in using dynamic_rnn over static_rnn?